# Loop through JSON and store values to PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON with the Following structure.

```
{

 "1":{"Itemname":"dtfg","unitprice":"12","Qty":"4","price":"$48.00"},
 "2":{"Itemname":"kjh","unitprice":"45","Qty":"7","price":"$315.00"},
 "3":{"Itemname":"yjk","unitprice":"76","Qty":"8","price":"$608.00"},
 "4":{"Itemname":"hgj","unitprice":"4","Qty":"45","price":"$180.00"}

}
```

I need the Itemname to be made into a PHP array, Unitprice into another one, Qty to another one and price to another one. How do I do that?

Comment: [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: I am not sure how can I use array_column here. Can you please show?

Comment: [Demo using array_column](https://3v4l.org/kP2C7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found out that the most efficientt way that solves my problem here would be to do like the following.

```
$cash=json_decode($new_json, true);

echo $arr3[1]['Itemname'];
echo $arr3[1]['unitprice'];
:
:
```

and so on.

This can be put into loops easily, fetched into HTML text-fields (as I want here in this scenario) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
$getArray   = get_object_vars(json_decode($json));
print_r($getArray);
echo $getArray[1]->Itemname;
echo $getArray[1]->unitprice;
```

you require `get_object_vars` as well for achieving your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$json =<<<JSONLIVES
{
     "1":{"Itemname":"dtfg","unitprice":"12","Qty":"4","price":"$48.00"},
     "2":{"Itemname":"kjh","unitprice":"45","Qty":"7","price":"$315.00"},
     "3":{"Itemname":"yjk","unitprice":"76","Qty":"8","price":"$608.00"},
     "4":{"Itemname":"hgj","unitprice":"4","Qty":"45","price":"$180.00"}
}
JSONLIVES;


$items = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$item_names = array();
foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    $item_names[] = $item['Itemname'];
}
```

Or Php >= 5.5

```
print_r(array_column($items, 'Itemname'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a function called `json_decode()` to convert your `json` data into `PHP array`

```
$json =  {

 "1":{"Itemname":"dtfg","unitprice":"12","Qty":"4","price":"$48.00"},
 "2":{"Itemname":"kjh","unitprice":"45","Qty":"7","price":"$315.00"},
 "3":{"Itemname":"yjk","unitprice":"76","Qty":"8","price":"$608.00"},
 "4":{"Itemname":"hgj","unitprice":"4","Qty":"45","price":"$180.00"}

};
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode your Json by PHP's [**json_decode()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

`$decodeJson` will return object then you can read `Itemname` and other values by using `$val->Itemname` in `foreach` loop

```
$json =  '{

 "1":{"Itemname":"dtfg","unitprice":"12","Qty":"4","price":"$48.00"},
 "2":{"Itemname":"kjh","unitprice":"45","Qty":"7","price":"$315.00"},
 "3":{"Itemname":"yjk","unitprice":"76","Qty":"8","price":"$608.00"},
 "4":{"Itemname":"hgj","unitprice":"4","Qty":"45","price":"$180.00"}

}';

$decodeJson = json_decode($json);

foreach($decodeJson as $key=>$val) {

      print_r($val);
}
```

[Live Json decode](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/47cb594f73bf30370e9aafbcd486db5ae4651a00)

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
$json = json_decode($json);

foreach($json as $obj){
   echo $obj->name;
   .....

}
```

Comment: While this code fragment may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful for future visitors if you explain why it solves the problem.